# Convergence of sampling from Brownian motion

Tags: brownian-motion, sampling

For a standard linear Brownian motion $\{B(t)\mid\ 0\le t\le 1\}$, for natural $n\ge 0$ and natural $1\le k\le 2^n$, let $d(n,k)=B\left(k2^{-n}\right)-B\left((k-1)2^{-n}\right)$ be the differences of height of the Brownian motion along the $k$'th $n$-diadic interval.

Denote the (random) sequence of averages of such differences as follows:
$$\mu_n = 2^{-n}\sum_{k=1}^{2^n}d(n,k)$$
and the sequence of standard deviations of such differences as follows:
$$\sigma_n = \sqrt{2^{-n}\sum_{k=1}^{2^n} \left(d(n,k) - \mu_n\right)^2}$$
and the sequence of *volatilities* as follows:
$$v_n = \sigma_n \cdot 2^{n/2}$$

**First question:** does it follow that $v_n$ converges almost surely?

**Second question:** does it follow that $v_n$ converges almost surely to 1?

**Third question:** if so, what can I say about the rate of convergence?

---

Some motivation / intuition: the story here is diadic sampling of a Brownian motion. The idea is that such a sampling should behave "properly" as the mesh goes to 0 (there's nothing special about "diadic" here). By properly I mean - having "annualized" standard deviation 1. To form such "annualizing", I remove the normalizing factor ($2^{-n}$) from the variance calculation.

The origin of the question about "rate of convergence" is in order to figure out what is a "proper mesh" of sampling, that will guarantee me behaviour which is "similar enough" to that of Brownian motion.

This is all done for a computer simulation, but the questions are here also for proper understanding of the subject.